# Would you like Code to periodically run 'git fetch'?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Установил Visual Studio Code, настроил в папке Git репозиторий, сделал первый commit потом push.

VS Code выдал мне вот такое сообщение:

[image: сообщение Visual Studio Code]

Что это?, Для чего? Нужно или нет?

Comment: Ниже верно написано. VSCode спрашивает нужно ли автоматизировать периодическое сравнение текущей локальной версии с тем что на сервере GIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, не вижу что у вас на картинке, но, предполагаю, что то же самое, что и в заголовке.

`get fetch` - это получить объекты с сервера, в том числе новые ветки, узнать куда "убежал" `master` пока вы работали у себя отдельно. Если над проектом работает больше одного человека, то функция полезна.

`git pull`, который вы делаете время от времени - это `fetch` + `merge`.

Также, если у вас не удался pull, по причине "убегания" удаленной ветки, то вы все равно делаете fetch или pull.

Так что fetch вы все равно регулярно делаете.